# using pull_all and push_all with python/mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have this object in Mongo:

```
mystuff = ListField(ReferenceField(Asset, dbref=True))
```

I have a Python method that is supposed to *update* the Mongo object, prepending its *mystuff* Listfield value with a given value. Because Mongoengine doesn't yet have a way to insert an object into a certain point in a list (and has [made it a low priority](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2362) to add this function), I've tried to:

1. save the contents of the current list to a temporary variable (*oldlist*)
2. *update* the DB entry, emptying the *mystuff* list using the "pull_all" modifier (which is part of [mongoengine](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html?highlight=update#atomic-updates))
3. *update* the DB entry again, pushing the newly added item to the *mystuff* list using update(push)
4. *update* the DB entry once again, using the "push_all" modifier and the *oldlist* variable to push the old stuff back onto the *mystuff* list.

It seems that "pull_all" requires some kind of modifier, but I'll be danged if I can figure out what it wants.

Anybody got any ideas? Of course the ideal situation would be to add an "insert_at" modifier to *update()*, but that's out of my hands. Life on the edge, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pull_all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pullAll/) takes a list of elements you want to pull out of the list.  In you're case I believe this will be `oldlist`.

However I think you're best bet is probably to retrieve the whole document with [`get`](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.get), modify the mystuff field in the client code, and send it back with a [`save`](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.save).

As you noted the tools for updating the document in place are limited.